# where to put 'source' info in a HTTP request?

Tags: http, http-headers

I have a web site where I want to record the source page from which a new HTTP request is made.  Is there a formal HTTP header field I can use to store this type of info?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `referer` field:

> This is the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed.

*From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)*

Answer (score 0):

The `Link:` header might be appropriate here:

```
Link: <http://example.org/>; rel="source"
```

The IANA website has a big list of potential values for `rel`:

https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml